# react-testing-library doesn't find element in this case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, tdd, react-testing-library

This is my test file:

```
import List from '../List';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

let data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

describe('Component: List', () => {
  let { container } = render(<List items={data} />);

  test('(1) list length', () => {
    let li = container.querySelectorAll('li');
    expect(li.length).toBe(3);
  });

  test('(2) values in list', () => {
    expect(screen.getByText('one')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('two')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('three')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

and I wrote this component:

```
const List = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        items.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

export default List;
```

My tests don't pass, I get this error for the `(2) values in list` :

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: one. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

In the event that, test (2) passes when I comment or remove test (1) :

```
describe('Component: List', () => {
  let { container } = render(<List items={data} />);

  // test('(1) list length', () => {
  //   let li = container.querySelectorAll('li');
  //   expect(li.length).toBe(3);
  // });

  test('(2) values in list', () => {
    expect(screen.getByText('one')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('two')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('three')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Does `container` effect on other selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because RTL will unmount React trees that were mounted with `render` after each test. This is called [cleanup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup).

> Please note that this is done automatically if the testing framework you're using supports the `afterEach` global and it is injected to your testing environment (like mocha, Jest, and Jasmine). If not, you will need to do manual cleanups after each test.

You only render the `List` component once in `describe` block. When the first test is finished, RTL will unmount the `List` component, there is nothing in "screen", that's why your second test failed.

There are two ways to solve this:

**1. [Skipping Auto Cleanup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#skipping-auto-cleanup)**

To make this even easier, you can also simply import `@testing-library/react/dont-cleanup-after-each which` will do the same thing. Just make sure you do this before importing `@testing-library/react`. You could do this with Jest's `setupFiles` configuration:

*If you are using jestjs as your testing framework*

```js
{
  // ... other jest config
  setupFiles: ['@testing-library/react/dont-cleanup-after-each']
}
```

But multiple test cases use the same component, and the order in which the tests are executed is out of order, which can cause tests to interact with each other.

**Simply put: Test cases are not isolated from each other and rely on the same test data**.

**2. Create fresh test data and test double for each test case， isolate tests.**

```
import List from './';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';

let data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

describe('Component: List', () => {
  // let { container } = render(<List items={data} />);

  test('(1) list length', () => {
    let { container } = render(<List items={data} />);
    let li = container.querySelectorAll('li');
    expect(li.length).toBe(3);
  });

  test('(2) values in list', () => {
    render(<List items={data} />);
    expect(screen.getByText('one')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('two')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('three')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Or, `render` the component in `beforeEach()` hook.

**update: How does RTL cleanup work?**

And reply to your comment: *does cleanup depend on each test() or it() blocks?*

Every time you mount the component in the container with `render` function, the [mountedContainers](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.4/src/pure.js#L52) set will add the component container.

[mountedContainers](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.4/src/pure.js#L28) set defined in module scope.

After each test, the [cleanup](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.4/src/pure.js#L103) function will unmount the component from the container, remove the container from the document, and remove the container from the `mountedContainers` set.

So you render the component in the `describe` function body, the describe function only executes once during the whole test. `mountedContainers` add your component once, When the first test case is performed, `mountedContainers` set will remove it. Then there is nothing in the "screen", the second test fails.

Comment: thank you, but does cleanup depend on each `test()` or `it()` blocks? you know, i was thinking to add one `render()` to improve performance... does it make sense for performance? especially for complex and heavy components??

Comment: @MartinRützy Cleanup happens in `afterEach()` hook automatically. I am not sure what do you mean by "does cleanup depend on each test() or it() blocks".  No measurement, no performance optimization, and I don't see any performance problems in this example. The first thing we should do is keep the tests independent, so they are more idempotent. We should ensure that the test code is correct and maintainable first, and performance second. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: @MartinRützy Updated answer, please check.